# how to insert values with scentific notation via fluentd into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

i have log with values like 5.0278483e+7 format.
bu ES ignore document with such values fully.
for example

```
5.0278483e+7,31504.0,172800.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.99,0.0,6732.0,3.1596388e+7,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,58.0,61973.0,8640.0,0.0,12.0,6732.0,8640.0,1000.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,72.32,20.2,8640.0,8640.0,7684763.0,101250.0,5.2743465e+7,0.0,0.0,6.219406e+7,10125
```

what i have to do ?

Comment: use tail for csv in fluentd

Answer (score 0):

i`m not sure but it seems fluentd is adding quotes in each field : "first (count)": "2e+3".
below is working (**no quotes** )

```
POST /test/doc
{ 
    "@timestamp" : "2016-09-07",
    "first (count)": 2e+3
}
w/o quotes e_notation working! 
same but with quotes "first (count)": "2e+3" not working
```

FYI : but normal notation is working **with quotes** also....

```
{   
    "@timestamp" : "2016-09-07",
    "first (count)": "9999"
}
```